# Plot a Python Matplotlib imshow (heatmap) from a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have a dictionary of lists:

```
dictA = {"A": [1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6], "C": [7,8,9]}
```

I want to display the data as a heatmap using the Matplotlib imshow. A, B and C run vertically (y), and the values are the corresponding cell value running left to right. This would result in a 3x3 plot.

Ideally, I would like to keep this native to core Python and avoid verbose data-type wrangling via packages like NumPy, but if it can't be helped, it can't be helped - I just want it to work.

The basics would be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dictA = {"A": [1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6], "C": [7,8,9]}
SOMETHING = #wrangling my dictionary to be "array-like"

plt.imshow(SOMETHING)
plt.show()
```

Comment: An approach using seaborn and pandas: `import pandas as pd; import seaborn as sns;
sns.heatmap(your_dict, annot=True)`. Please avoid using the build-in name `dict` as a variable name, as that would make the built-in name inaccessible.

Comment: Forgive my typo - corrected. Thanks for the suggestion. My preference would be to keep the code as core as possible, avoiding importing data-wrangling packages like pandas and numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a heatmap using matplotlib with the given dictionary of lists, you can use a nested list comprehension to convert the dictionary into an "array-like" format. While numpy is often used for more complex data manipulations, you can avoid using it for this simple task. Here's a way to achieve the heatmap without numpy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Your dictionary of lists
data_dict = {"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "C": [7, 8, 9]}

# Convert the dictionary into an array-like format (list of lists)
array_like_data = [[data_dict[col][row] for col in data_dict] for row in 
range(len(data_dict["A"]))]

# Create the heatmap
plt.imshow(array_like_data, cmap='viridis', aspect='auto', origin='upper')

# Add labels to the axes
plt.xticks(range(len(data_dict)), list(data_dict.keys()))
plt.yticks(range(len(data_dict["A"])), range(1, len(data_dict["A"]) + 1))

# Show the plot
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is precisely what I wanted. Also, thank you for avoiding numpy. Every tutorial on imshow I found used numpy, even for basic examples - that goes against so many software engineering principles.

Comment: @Anthony I have to say I'm quite suspicious that this answer is AI-generated…

Comment: @AnthonyNash Numpy is really unavoidable if you want to do more advanced data manipulation or visualization.  A library such as matplotlib internally makes heavy use of numpy. Nowadays, numpy is almost considered a core part of Python. It both brings speed and handy array operations. (You are right in trying to better understand how Python works and avoid numpy.)

Comment: @mozway it works, so I'm happy. Interestingly, if you suspect this is generated by an AI, then it's not an artificial intelligence - as per the Turing Test. Just a little joke.

Comment: @mozway If it is AI-generated, it is quite well done: it takes into account a lot of details (such as using the dict keys for the labeling and using `origin='upper'`). It also doesn't add too much of the blabla that AI usually generates.

Comment: @JohanC that's why I said "suspicious" and acknowledged the correctness ;)

Answer (score 2):

Provided that your dictionary values have been added in the correct order (and that you are [working with Python 3.6 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/7395592)), the simplest version would be:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dictA = {"A": [1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6], "C": [7,8,9]}
plt.imshow(dictA.values())
plt.show()
```

This would create an image layout with each dictionary value forming a *row*, that is:

```
123
456
789
```

If the question, instead, was meant in the sense that each dictionary value should form a *column*, that is:

```
147
258
369
```

… then this could be achieved by replacing the `plt.imshow()` call above with:

```py
plt.imshow(list(zip(*dictA.values())))
```

Thanks to @mozway for pointing out the ambiguity and providing the corresponding second solution.

Comment: That would not provide the correct orientation, you'd need: `plt.imshow(list(zip(*data_dict.values())))`

Comment: @mozway I understood it this way:  "A, B and C run vertically (y)" meaning A being the fist row, B being the second, C being the third, and "the values are the corresponding cell value running left to right" meaning 1 being left, 2 being center, 3 being right, etc. This should be fulfilled with my solution, right?

Comment: fair enough, it's indeed ambiguous. That doesn't match the accepted answer so OP should clarify ;)

Comment: @mozway: Fully agree, and I only noticed the ambiguity through your comment!